# Showing that $i\arg(e^{2z})=2iy?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does $i\arg(e^{2z})=2iy?$ If it does I have solved my problem, and hence it seems like it must  be the case, but I don't see it.

$$i\arg(e^{2z})=i\arg(e^{2x+2iy})=i\arg(e^{2x}e^{2iy})\implies \theta=2y(?)$$ Why does the $2x$ get 'ignored'?

Comment: I am starting to suspect this isn't the case

Comment: Remember $\arg(cz)=\arg(z)$ for any nonzero real constant $c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property of the argument is $\arg(z_1z_2) = \arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$. Therefore, 
$$
\arg(e^{2x}e^{2iy}) = \arg(e^{2x})+\arg(e^{2iy})
$$
For $\arg\in(-\pi,\pi)$, what is $ \arg(e^{2x})$?

Comment: Ahh I see treat $z=e^{2x}$ and clearly $y=0$ and hence $\arctan(\frac{y}{x}=\arctan(0)=0$

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$? its irrevelant

Comment: @sandstone why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Identitycrisis $e^{2x}$ is a real number so the argument is $0+2i\pi k$ for $k$ and integer.

Comment: @dustin see apple's comment under the question. Real numbers just make the distance from the origin different and dont vary the angle

Comment: @sandstone read it awhile ago. What is your point? The question says $e^{2z}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $z=x+iy$. By definition, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it becomes a little clearer when looking at the principal branch of the logarithm:

$$\log z = \ln |z| + i\arg z$$
So $\arg (e^{2z}) = \Im \log(e^{2z}) = \Im 2z = 2\Im z = 2y$. Note that we have assumed $y\in (-\pi, \pi)$ and your equality is only valid in this case. What you can always say is that
$$i\arg (e^{2z}) = 2yi + 2\pi i k$$
for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: I think you made someone angry since they only targeted your post.

Comment: @dustin I guess so (although I don't know who that may be). Such behaviour seems to accumulate recently... Every other day I see downvotes (also for other users) without any apparent reason or comment.

Comment: Just flag it and write a mod comment saying you think the last few post have been by a certain user. One user used to downvote many of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}i\arg(e^{2z})&=i\arg(e^{2x+2iy}) \\ 
&=i\arg(e^{2x}e^{2iy}) \\
&=i\arg(e^{2x}(\cos2y+i\sin2y)) \\
&=i\arg((\cos2y+i\sin2y)) \ \  \text{ as $e^{2x} \in \mathbb{R}$} \\
&=i(2y) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ by definition}  \\
\end{align}$$